# PHP get something from a html file, then pass something back to the original html file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am very new to php,
Suppose, I have a index.html, and a cal.php, in a directory.

index.html:

```
<head>
    <script>
        some java script here used to display graphs based on cal.php calculated results
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="cal.php" method="post">
        <div class="row x_title">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>Dashboard</h3>
            </div>
            <select class="form-control" id="myFileSelect">
                <?php
                echo '<option>Choose file</option>';
                foreach (glob('Report' . '/*.csv') as $file) {
                    list($af, $bf) = split("/", $file, 2);
                    list($filenam, $extnt) = split(".", $bf, 1);
                    echo '<option value="' . $bf . '">' . $filenam . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

cal.php

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$output
/* pass the output back to original html */
/* let's say pass this php variable $output to the javascript on original html */
?>
```

I want to post the form when user hit submit, pass some value to cal.php, doing some calculations in the cal.php file, then pass the variable $output to original html's JavaScript variable.

I'm kind of blank on between how php works with a html page.

Some one could help me? Or give me some ideas?

Comment: you can also use session for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ajax you can do it. The ajax request from index.html will be calling cal.php The cal.php should echo the result you wantand in the success function of ajax you get the response.

Comment: Thanks,could you provide some tutorial or links that i can check? About the Ajex stuff?